# Facebook Graph API: "Unsupported get request" when trying to get public information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

until now I thought it was possible to retrieve the public information of every user when making a get request to https://graph.facebook.com/user_id.

But I just noticed a user where I am getting this as response

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

It's also not possible to get a custom profile-picture via http://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?width=100&height=75.

But the user/page can be viewed even if I am not logged in to Facebook. So I just can't access the public user information via the Graph API (without access token).

I think the user might have (de)activated something in the privacy settings which disables retrieving public information with the Graph API. Do you know more about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Open Graph returns false](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10622558/facebook-open-graph-returns-false)

Comment: (the error has been updated to be a proper exception instead of 'false' since that question) - see also my answer on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11135053/fetching-list-of-friends-in-graph-api-or-fql-appears-to-be-missing-some-friend/11135150#11135150
 for other reasons you'd get this error attempting to access a user ID directly

Comment: Thank you that might be the reason. Then the only way to get these information from the user will be using the access token (he has authorized my app). Does anyone know if it's possible to retrieve multiple users in one request using access tokens?

Comment: I also get this error when trying to access `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/apprequests` via the iOS SDK v3.1 using `[[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"apprequests"] startWithCompletionHandler:]`. If I run this request with `curl`, using the same access token as my `FBSession` is using, it works.

Comment: Duh, I must specify `me/` as part of the graph path, so the proper invocation is: `[[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/apprequests"]`